# Proof of Goursat's lemma in Serre's Finite Groups An Introduction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On page 8 in Serre's *Finite Groups An Introduction* about the proof of Goursat's lemma it states that:

> Proposition 1.6 (Goursat's lemma). For $i=1,2$ , let $N_i$ be a normal subgroup of $G_i$ and let $\varphi : G_1/N_1\to G_2/N_2$ be an isomorphism. Let $H_{N_1,N_2,\varphi}$ be the set of all $(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$ which are such that $\varphi(\bar{g_1})=\bar{g_2}$ where $\bar{g_i}$ is the image of $g_i$ in $G_i/N_i$ . Then:
>
> i) $\text{pr}_i(H_{N_1,N_2,\varphi})=G_i$ for $i= 1,2$ .
>
> ii) Every subgroup $H$ of $G_1\times G_2$ such that $\mathrm{pr}_i(H)= G_i$ for $i = 1,2$ is equal to some $H_{N_1,N_2,\varphi}$ for a unique choice of $N_1,N_2$ and $\varphi$ .
>
> [Note that $H_{N_1,N_2,\varphi}$ may be viewed as a kind of graph of $\varphi$ .]
>
> Proof of ii). Define $N_1$ as $H\cap G_1$ , where $G_1$ is viewed as a subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$ , namely the kernel of $\text{pr}_2$ . Define similarly $N_2 = H\cap G_2$ . By assumption, we have $H.G_1=G_1\times G_2$ , since both $H$ and $G_2$ normalize $H$ and $G_1$ , this shows that $G_1\times G_2$ normalizes $N_1$ , i.e., that $N_1$ is normal in $G_1$ . Similarly $N_2$ is normal in $G_2$ . $\cdots$

In the proof of part ii , the author says that "since both $H$ and $G_2$ normalize $H$ and $G_1$ ", but I can not see how to show that $G_2\leqslant\mathbf{N}_{G_1\times G_2}(H)$ . If so, then similarly we have $G_1\leqslant\mathbf{N}_{G_1\times G_2}(H)$ . Pick arbitrary $(g_1,1)\in G_1$ and $(1,g_2)\in G_2$ we obtain $(g_1,g_2)=(g_1,1)(g_2,1)\in\mathbf{N}_{G_1\times G_2}(H)$ since both $G_1$ and $G_2$ normalize $H$ , this forces $G_1\times G_2=\mathbf{N}_{G_1\times G_2}(H)$ , then $H$ must be normal in $G_1\times G_2$ .

Comment: I would replace "$H$ and $G_1$" by "$H\cap G_1$".

Answer (score 3):

I think this is perhaps less than clear and you are misinterpreting what is meant. Rather than "$H$ and $G_1$", it's probably best to say that $H$ normalizes both $H$ and $G_1$, and $G_2$ *centralizes* $G_1$, hence normalizes $H\cap G_1$. I also think there is a typo there.

Explicitly: we want to show $H\cap(G_1\times\{1\})$ is normal. Note $G_2$ centralizes $G_1\times\{1\}$, so it centralizes (hence normalizes) any subgroup of $G_1\times\{1\}$; in particular it normalizes $H\cap (G_1\times\{1\})$. And $H$ normalizes both $H$ and $G_1\times\{1\}$ (the latter because it is normal in $G_1\times G_2$). So $H$ normalizes $H\cap (G_1\times\{1\})$. Thus, both $H$ and $G_2$ normalize $H\cap (G_1\times \{1\})$.

Now, (*typo alert*) we have $HG_2=G_1\times G_2$. Since $H$ and $G_2$ both normalize $H\cap(G_1\times\{1\})$, and $H$ and $G_2$ generate $G_1\times G_2$, it follows that $H\cap (G_1\times\{1\})$ is normal in $G_1\times G_2$. The symmetric argument, using $G_1$ instead of $G_2$ and that $HG_1=G_1\times G_2$, shows that $H\cap(\{1\}\times G_2)$ is normal in $G_1\times G_2$.

Comment: Do you you mean that $H$ does not necessarily normalize $G_1 $? I have finished the proof following your leading. Thanks!

Comment: @DianWei $H$ normalizes both $G_1$ and $G_2$, because both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal in $G_1\times G_2$, and $H\leq G_1\times G_2$. I think you mean to ask whether $G_1$ (or $G_2$) normalize $H$. They need not. Take $G_1=G_2=S_3$, and take $H$ to be the diagonal subgroup $H=\{(x,x)\mid x\S_3\}$. Then $H$ is not normalized by either $S_3\times\{1\}$ nor by $\{1\}\times S_3$.

Comment: Yes, I had a doubt on whether $G_2\leqslant\mathbf{N}_{G_1\times G_2}(H)$ , it is a typo in my initial comment. Thanks for your counter-example.